# Json from Mysql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Hi I'm grabbing my table with php and getting this output

```
{"id":"1","player":"123","name":"his_name","reason":"reason text","instance":"1","lastupdated":"datetime"}
```

however I am looking to get somthing like this

```
text{"id":"1","player":"123","name":"his_name","reason":"reason text","instance":"1","lastupdated":"datetime"}
```

current php:

```
mysql_connect($dbhost.':'.$dbport, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die (mysql_error());

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT *"."FROM `table_name` Order By id Desc;");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}

print json_encode($rows);
```

db structure:

```
player | name | reason | instance | lastupdated
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why do you want to append `text` ?

Comment: the way I am polling it I need to have the text there, I've seen it on various API's such as twitch's kraken api.

Comment: adding text like that renders the json invalid. unless you're doing this as a king of jsonp-type response, there's no point in adding text outside of the json string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add only a key before the complete result set you get from the database. As I understand from your example link.

Then you can update your code like this:

```
 // Assuming $rows is already populated with desired data.

$res = array();
$res['text'] = $rows;

print_r(json_encode($res));
```

Output:

```
{"text":{"id":1,"player":123,"name":"his_name","reason":"reason text","instance":1,"lastupdated":"datetime"}}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for Its just I did not know how to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prepend a literal text, you can use the string concatenation operator with the print:

```
print "text" . json_encode($rows);
```

Does this work for you? But what should be the content for the `text`?

Comment: example; http://api.twitch.tv/api/team/teamliquid/live_channels.json the way they have -channel --name --description --etc...

Comment: Ah... So, you are technically appending an array, before this array, right?